# View under Navbar bug

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin Auth via dependency services which presents a new view where the user authenticates However, when the modal page appears and is fully visible, it jumps up and down revealing this black bar [image: Black Bar]
It quickly disapears and the page loads like so: [image] where the top of the page is hidden. Thanks in advance

I've tried the following:

```
        UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        UIViewController viewController = window.RootViewController;
        UIViewController AuthVC = auth.GetUI();

        AuthVC.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
        AuthVC.ExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false;
        AuthVC.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;

        viewController.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
        viewController.ExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false;
        viewController.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;

        viewController.PresentViewController(AuthVC, true, null);
```

The UIViewController from Auth.GetUI() comes from this package: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth

Comment: I see you have post this same issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767688/view-under-navbar , please delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my temp fix, It still flashes but it looks correct after if has loaded. Does anyone know what would cause the black bar flashing?

```
viewController.PresentViewController(AuthVC, true, new Action(() =>
{
    var MainUIView = AuthVC.View.Subviews[0];
    var MainNavBar = AuthVC.View.Subviews[1];
    var NavBarHeight = MainNavBar.Frame.Y + MainNavBar.Frame.Height;
    MainUIView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, NavBarHeight, MainUIView.Frame.Width, MainUIView.Frame.Height - NavBarHeight);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
viewController.NavigationController.PresentViewController(AuthVC, true, new Action(() =>
{
    var MainUIView = AuthVC.View.Subviews[0];
    var MainNavBar = AuthVC.View.Subviews[1];
    var NavBarHeight = MainNavBar.Frame.Y + MainNavBar.Frame.Height;
    MainUIView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, NavBarHeight, MainUIView.Frame.Width, MainUIView.Frame.Height - NavBarHeight);
}));
```

Comment: I tried this, and the flashing occurs with or without this additional code. Also, when doing this before presenting, the calculations are wrong and the view is only slightly hidden.